# How to read files from dist folder java

Tags: java

This is probably a repeated question asked by several people, but i could not understand after searching the answers.

netbeans creates a folder dist after a build operation. I want to place a text file in that folder, the jar file should read the text file.

The target platforms are windows and linux

structure of the folders,

```
.java file  =  C:\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\Example\src\example
 build folder = C:\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\Example
 build folder contains classes folder. classes folder contains all the class files
 dist folder = C:\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\Example
 dist folder contains the .jar files and i want to place a text file inside this folder
```

the,

```
 getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("example.txt");
```

seems to work only if the path is along with .java files.

Thanks

Comment: Not too sure if you can directly load it as "example.txt" with no directories, but if you create a folder inside dist - ie "Text files" you can do /textfiles/example.txt

Comment: So you may be able to load it directly, but I'm too lazy to try it...

Answer (score -1):

To read some files from inside jar you should do:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("path/to/file");
```

See:[File loading by getClass().getResource()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14089228/10330374)